# Disabled button functional, not working properly

Tags: javascript

```
$("#qty-plus3").click(function() {
    var val = parseInt($("#qty3").val(),10);
    $("#qty3").val(val+1);
    $("#add-to-cart").removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('view-disable').addClass('view-add');
    $('#wednesday').attr('value',$("#qty3").val());
});

$("#qty-minus3").click(function() {
    var val = parseInt($("#qty3").val(),10);
    if(val != 0) {
        $("#qty3").val(val-1);
        $('#wednesday').attr('value',$("#qty3").val());
        $("#add-to-cart").removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('view-disable').addClass('view-add');
    }

});
```

This works that when the value is more than one my "Add to Cart" becomes enabled, then I realized that if I add one, then I remove one, my button should go back to being disabled but now it stays enabled even when both are 0. For example I land on page its disabled, then I add , it gets enabled then I remove so that it is back to 0 , it is still enabled, how can I fix it and make it disabled if there is 0 on it?
I tired this but it didnt work inside the minus function

```
$("#qty-minus3").click(function() {
    var val = parseInt($("#qty3").val(),10);
    if(val != 0) {
        $("#qty3").val(val-1);
        $('#wednesday').attr('value',$("#qty3").val());
        $("#add-to-cart").removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('view-disable').addClass('view-add');
    }
    if (val == 0)
    {
        $("#add-to-cart").addAttr('disabled').addClass('view-disable').removeClass('view-add');
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: There is no `addAttr()` method in jquery as far as I know. You probably want to use `attr()` or `prop()` in this case.

Comment: Use `.prop('disabled', true/false)`

Comment: Does my solution work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.prop('disabled', true)` instead. Your working code will look like this.

```
 $("#qty-minus3").click(function() {
    var val = parseInt($("#qty3").val(), 10);
    if (val != 0) {
        $("#qty3").val(val - 1);
        $('#wednesday').attr('value', $("#qty3").val());
        $("#add-to-cart").removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('view-disable').addClass('view-add');
    }
    else if (val == 0) {
        $("#add-to-cart").prop('disabled', true).addClass('view-disable').removeClass('view-add');
    }
});
```

Comment: I have to click 0 twice then it becomes disabled, not when it first becomes 0 , how can I solve this?